# Recommend SSL certificate to receive sensitive data (Standard Vs Extended validation certificate)

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

I have a WCF service to receive sensitive data ( like SSN,Name,address,Driver License), To make sure information is securely transmitted and not accessible for anyone to view/change, I need to install SSL server certificate on clients server.

I am looking for recommendations to choose correct certificate for service. there are couple of certs available online
1. Standard cert
2. Extended validation certificate.
3. SSL Plus
4. Extended validation plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of validation (i.e. domain, organization, extended, etc.) of an SSL certificate has only meaning to an end user; a simple domain validation certificate will let you setup a secure communication between you clients and your server.

The higher validation levels only give to a human more confidence about the site he / she is visiting, because a higher certificate level means that the organization has passed through more checks than with a simpler certificate.

If you're concerned about data communication security (and if you need it between two programs, without direct user intervention), you should instead turn your attention to encryption protocols and key lengths.

According to [Qualys SSL Labs Best Practices](https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_TLS_Deployment_Best_Practices.pdf), you should use 2048-bit RSA or 256-bit ECDSA private keys (I suggest you to read the whole guide).

As in all processes that involve encryption, higher levels of encryption means higher security, but lower performance, so choose wisely.

After you have chosen and installed the certificate, be sure to check your server with their [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html), to be sure that your whole encryption chain is secure enough and correctly configured.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Watery !